# GAS sends multiple slack notifications

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, notifications, slack

I'd like to send notifications to slack using Google Apps Scripts.
It's supposed to happen when any change is made on Gsheet but sometimes the program sends multiple notifications even after only a single change.
I guess my code has any fault or the triggers cause any problem - because I apply this function to more than one sheet.
But it doesn't happen "always", so is it an error caused by GAS specification?
My code is as below. Any idea or advice will be appreciated.

```
function slackNotification(sheetname,slack_channel){
  Logger.log(sheetname)
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var myActiveRange = mySheet.getActiveRange();
  var lastRow = mySheet.getLastRow();
  var pdfColumn = PDF_column_n
  var checkColumn = slack_column_n
  Logger.log(lastRow)

  var unslacked = []; 
  for (var i=1; i <= lastRow; i++){
    var cell = mySheet.getRange(i, checkColumn);
    if(cell.isBlank()){
      Logger.log(i + "is not yet notified");
      unslacked.push(i);
    }
  }
  Logger.log("unslcked yet"+unslacked)

  for (var i=unslacked[0]; i <= unslacked[unslacked.length - 1]; i++){
      var pdfCell = mySheet.getRange(extention_column+i) 
      var checkSlack = mySheet.getRange(slack_column+i) 
      Logger.log(checkSlack.isBlank())
      Logger.log(pdfCell.getValue())

      if (pdfCell.getValue() == "pdf" && checkSlack.isBlank() == true)
      {
        var requestId = mySheet.getRange(request_column+i).getValue();
        var clientId = mySheet.getRange(client_column+i).getValue();
        var claimId = mySheet.getRange(claim_column+i).getValue();
        var groupId = mySheet.getRange(group_column+i).getValue();
        Logger.log(groupId)

        if (branches.includes(groupId)){
        var message = "\nrequestId:" + requestId + "\nclientId:" + clientId + "\nclaimId:" + claimId
        var postUrl = slack_channel
        var username = 'botbot';  
        var icon = ':hatching_chick:';  
        var jsonData =
        {
          "username" : username,
          "icon_emoji": icon,
          "text" : message,
          link_names: 1
        };
        var payload = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

        var options =
        {
          "method" : "post",
          "contentType" : "application/json",
          "payload" : payload
        };

        UrlFetchApp.fetch(postUrl, options);
        checkSlack.setValue(true);
    }
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: About `It's supposed to happen when any change is made on Gsheet`, in your script, you are using the OnEdit trigger? If my understanding is correct, how is the function `slackNotification` called? And in your situation, when you use LockService, that will be able to be the method for removing your issue? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the comment. I use OnChange as the trigger. I'm afraid I don't understand what you really mean by `how is the function slackNotification called?`. Lock stuff is not what I want at this moment. I just wanna filter the possibilities causing the unexpected result - if my code is wrong or GAS specification does something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, you have used OnChange trigger. About `how is the function slackNotification called?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I wanted to know the method for executing your function `slackNotification`. For example, `slackNotification` is installed as the OnChange trigger? And also, I understood that you don't want to use the LockService. I couldn't notice this from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your quick reply. Let me tell you that your English is not poor at all. I made another function just to call `slackNotification` in another file and the trigger is set up with this another function. appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when you put `break` just after the line of `checkSlack.setValue(true);`, what result will you obtain? When `break` is used, after `UrlFetchApp.fetch(postUrl, options)` was run, the loop is finished. By this, only one-time request is achieved. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. If this was not also the direction you expect as the same with LockService, I apologize again.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you have within your project more than one function called `slackNotification`? Also, can you verify how many triggers you have installed?

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks for the comment. Yeah as you say 5 different functions call `slackNotification` and each has each `onChange` trigger set. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) are bound project-based, not script filed based

- If you have multiple functions with the same name in your project - there is no way to know to which one the trigger becomes bound.
- Most likely your 5 onChange triggers are all bound to the same function and thus the function is executed multiple times (sending multiple Slack notifications as a result)
- It does not make a difference if the functions are located within the same script file or within different script files within the same project
- Splitting up your code into different code files is only for visibility/structure purposes, for the trigger the functions are still located all within the same project

**Solution**

- Remove from your project all existing triggers that are bound to functions with not unique names
- Give to all functions in your **project** (not just script file) unique names and save all script files
- Install new triggers either [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) or [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)
- Now you can be sure that each trigger is bound to a different function
- Mind that if the content of your functions is the same (e.g. containing request to send Slack notifications), this content will be executed the same amount of times as the number of respective triggers in your project, so if the content of your functions is identical, you actually need to keep only one function bound to one trigger and remove all the functions of identic content.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Then why does it happen once in a while? I'm convinced by what you're saying if it happens every time. But in most cases it succeeds and I get two or three or so notifications just 'sometimes'. There is no rule for this behavior.

Comment: As you say - there is no rule, because when your project contains more than one function with the same name -the behaviour is undefined, especially if you have triggers bound to functions with non-unique names.

Comment: They all have unique names.

Comment: But you said you have five different funciton called `slackNotification()` or did I get you wrong? Even if they are called all differently, but there are multiple functions bound to an onChange trigger which all send a slack notification - then you will send also send multiple notifications, since all functions will be executed in case of a change.